# How to get the base url of your WebApp in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I would like to get the base Url of my .NET 6 Web Application server. The issue is that I want to get it in the `Program.cs` file and not inside a Controller.

The reason for this is because `Program.cs` is where i populate my database with objects and i would like to give these objects a string property that contains the current base Url of the website.

Is this possible?

Comment: How is your web application going to run? (in Kestrel, IIS, ... ?)  
Is there any configuration for the base url in the appsettings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a lot going on during startup of the web application, you have not everything available at this time.
One thing you could do, is register a delegate when the `ApplicationStarted` token has been canceled:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var app = builder.Build();

    app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

    app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
    {
        ICollection<string> urls = app.Urls; // The list of URLs that the HTTP server is bound to
    });

    app.Run();
}
```

Comment: That's very clever to use a delegate. This works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to get urls on which your application is listening but only after it is running.

You can try this. but I am not sure how it will fit into your solution.

```
await app.StartAsync();

Console.WriteLine($"Urls from Program.cs after app.StartAsync(): {string.Join(", ", app.Urls)}");

await app.WaitForShutdownAsync();
```